# Man is bitten by a snake and survives an epidemic apocalypse. Dies later of appendicitis

Tags: story-identification, books

The main character is bitten by a snake and afterwards recovers but finds that almost all humanity died of an epidemic.

Finally he finds some people to leave with and becomes a sort of legend but dies of appendicitis.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [*Earth Abides*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Abides) (1949) by George R. Stewart.

> While working on his graduate thesis in geology in the Sierra Nevada
> mountains, Ish is bitten by a rattlesnake. As he heals from the bite,
> taking refuge in a cabin, he gets sick with a disease that looks like
> measles, and he moves in and out of consciousness (at one point being
> approached by two men who flee in fright). He recovers and makes his
> way back to civilization, only to discover that it has utterly
> collapsed—most people had died from the same disease.

For the record, he himself dies of old age. His wife dies of cancer, which he first mistakes for appendicitis.

> Sometimes, in those grim months that followed, he thought to himself,
> "This may be merely appendicitis, The pain is in that place. Why can I
> not operate? I can read the books. I could find out how it is done.
> One of the boys could manage the ether. At worst, I would only end the
> pain."

Comment: Wow, Berkeley in 1949. Dollars to donuts this guy knew, maybe even was friends with, Oppenheimer (who was known to stray from physics). I get nostalgic. Reminds me also of PKD, also just becoming or about to become active as a writer and lived in Berkeley, writing of the Bay Area.

Comment: What a great and complete answer.